# Azure IoT Hub Client - How to upload files in application/json format

Tags: azure, content-type, azure-iot-hub

I have Azure IoT Hub Python. Trying to upload the files through this routine

```
def iothub_file_upload_sample_run():
try:
    print ( "IoT Hub file upload sample, press Ctrl-C to exit" )
    client = IoTHubClient(CONNECTION_STRING, PROTOCOL)      

    f = open(PATHTOFILE, "r")
    content = f.read()

    client.upload_blob_async(FILENAME, content, len(content), blob_upload_conf_callback)

    print ( "" )
    print ( "File upload initiated..." )
```

This works fine but the files content types are "application/octet-stream"

I went to some posts and tried by adding "client.set_options('auto_url_encode_decode', True)" as below

```
def iothub_file_upload_sample_run():
try:
    print ( "IoT Hub file upload sample, press Ctrl-C to exit" )

    client = IoTHubClient(CONNECTION_STRING, PROTOCOL)
    client.set_options('auto_url_encode_decode', True)

    f = open(PATHTOFILE, "r")
    content = f.read()

    client.upload_blob_async(FILENAME, content, len(content), blob_upload_conf_callback)

    print ( "" )
    print ( "File upload initiated..." )


But the response message is 
File:C:\Release\iot-sdks- 
internals\release\python\automation\aziotsdk_pytools\src\c\c- 
utility\adapters\httpapi_winhttp.c Func:HTTPAPI_CloneOption Line:1046 
unknown option auto_url_encode_decode
```

unknown option auto_url_encode_decode and Protocol is HTTP

Not sure if this is limitation of Azure IoT Hub Python to default send Application/octet-stream

Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that the **Python SDK** calls the [IoTHubClient_UploadToBlobAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-c-sdk-ref/iothub-client-h/iothubclient-uploadtoblobasync) method that doesn't support setting the content type.

You could use a dedicated server side triggered component (such as an **Azure Function**) to change the content type of the **Azure Blob** to the correct one (see [BlockBlobService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice.blockblobservice?view=azure-python) and [ContentSettings class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.models.contentsettings?view=azure-python)).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to *IoTHubClient_UploadToBlobAsync* method is using a REST API calls. The following steps shows this sequence:

1. POST to [Create File Upload Sas Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/createfileuploadsasuri)
2. PUT to Upload blob file
3. POST to [Update File Upload Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/updatefileuploadstatus)

Note, that the step 2. can handle a full requirements for your upload process such as metadata, properties, contents, etc.